# getting a `InValid URL` when I send a voice message

Tags: javascript, typescript, ffmpeg, openai-whisper

When I try to send voice messages I always get invalid url error with. I am using whisper to convert the audio to text but for some reason I cannot seem to pass the file to the whisper. It worked when I used this in java script but not in typescript for some reason

```
async function createFile(path: string): Promise<File> {
  const response = await fetch(path);
  const data = await response.blob();
  
  // Extract file name from the path
  const fileName = path.split('/').pop() || 'unknown';
  
  // Extract file extension and determine MIME type
  const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase() || '';
  const mimeTypes: Record<string, string> = {
    'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
    // Add more mappings as needed
  };
  const fileType = mimeTypes[fileExtension] || 'application/octet-stream';
  
  const metadata = {
    type: fileType
  };
  
  return new File([data], fileName, metadata);
}

async function sendAudioForTranscription(file_path:string) {
  try {
    
    // const audioData = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
    const audioFile = await createFile(file_path)

    const response = await openai.createTranscription(audioFile, "whisper-1");
    const transcribed = response.data.text;

    return transcribed;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error transcribing the audio:", error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I am new to this so any help would be appreciated. This is the error

```
Error transcribing the audio: TypeError: Failed to parse URL from src\audio_files\false_xxxxxxxxx8@c.us_B161BC6FA04DB01B8B31F5E0F83EDAD5.mp3
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:778:13)
      at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7132:25)
      at fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10715:25)
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11574:18)
      at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:270:25)
      at C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:28:32
      at C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:4:12)
      at createFile (C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:27:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:49:37)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at C:\Users\Ammad Ali\Documents\Documents\alex-whatsapp-bot\build\openai\transcript.js:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
    input: 'src\\audio_files\\false_xxxxxxxxx8@c.us_B161BC6FA04DB01B8B31F5E0F83EDAD5.mp3',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
  }
}
```

To get a response back in voice message

Comment: The url is invalid. How are you calling sendAudioForTranscription

Comment: @mplungjan sorry I don't understand. what do you mean?

Comment: `sendAudioForTranscription(file_path:string) {` is getting `src\audio_files\false_xxxxxxxxx8@c.us_B161BC6FA04DB01B8B31F5E0F83EDAD5.mp3` which should be `src/audio_files/false_xxxxxxxxx8@c.us_B161BC6FA04DB01B8B31F5E0F83EDAD5.mp3` or perhaps even the `@` would need to be `%40`